# Remove bullets on menu items of Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

An MVC4 Bootstrap example app shows bullet points placed way ahead of the navigation menu items on the navigation bar. separated by brand, even. The bullets appears to be related to  tags CSS. Does any one have a clue about removing the bullets? The  menu is displayed by navigationextension.cs

```
       <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                      @Html.Navigation()
                </div>
```

Comment: A screenshot (linked) of what you get and what you want could help.

Comment: ..menu items are related to A tags..., the original text this part was edited out. Thanks

Comment: not enough "reputation" to add a picture, sorry. But this addition makes it work.  /*.nav-collapse .collapse li
 {
  list-style-type: none;
 }*/
 li
 {
  list-style-type: none;
  
 }   Thanks all

Comment: That's why I said linked, you should be able to add links to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to target the list item (.nav-collapse .li) with the following CSS property:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

Comment: It's not clear whether this is a workaround or a definitive, necessary fix for bootstrap. It seems to me that this is probably an indicator of an issues with one's bootstrap setup.

Answer (score 4):

you can also add class="list-unstyled" to the ul to remove all the bullets.

Removes all default list-style (bullets, left margin, etc.) styling from a  or  list.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp

Answer (score 1):

In case others arrive with a similar issue in Edge with `.dropdown-menu`

```
/* Edge fix */
.dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

Note: The 2nd selector covers our custom multi-column dropdowns and can be ignored

Comment: Indicated this was not for the OP issue. Added because I ended up here for a very similar issue. If you're going to downvote, provide an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Add `navbar-nav dropdown` to the class

Answer (score 1):

Try adding style none to li class `<li class="nav-item" style="list-style-type: none;" >`

Answer (score 1):

**Simply add the "list-unstyled"** to the class of the `<li>` element.

For example, change this:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
```

to this:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown list-unstyled">
```

#### Example from [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/)

This has a random dot:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The only change is I added `list-unstyled` and there's no dot anymore!

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown list-unstyled">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with bullets, plus the `<li>` elements where invading each other spaces. I solved it by assigning the `"nav"` class to the `<ul>` element instead of the `"navbar"` class I was using.
This is a sample of the working list of elements:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect('recipe')">Recipes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect('shopping-list')">Shopping List</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this a sample of the list of elements showing up with bullets and overlapped:

```
<ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect('recipe')">Recipes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect('shopping-list')">Shopping List</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is working at least with Bootsrap version 3.

I found the explanation for this is at the treehouse page: [What's the difference between nav and navbar?](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/whats-the-difference-between-nav-and-navbar#:%7E:text=A%20%22navbar%22%20is%20an%20area,other%20elements%20related%20to%20navigation.)